# How to I find the equilibrium temperature in this problem?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, phase

From Castellan's *Physical Chemistry*, chapter 12 [1, p. 276]:

> **12.18** At $\pu{25 °C}$ we have for rhombic sulfur: $ΔG_\mathrm{f}^\circ = 0,$ $ΔS^\circ = \pu{31.88 ± 0.17 J K-1 mol-1};$ and for monoclinic sulfur: $ΔG_\mathrm{f}^\circ = \pu{63 J mol-1},$ $ΔS^\circ = \pu{32.55 ± 0.25 J K-1 mol-1}.$ Assuming that the entropies do not vary with temperature, sketch the value of $μ$ versus $T$ for the two forms of sulfur. From the data determine the equilibrium temperature for the transformation of rhombic sulfur to monoclinic sulfur. Compare this temperature with the experimental value, $\pu{95.4 °C},$ noting the uncertainties in the values of $ΔS^\circ.$

I have plotted the graph of $μ$ vs $T$ successfully, but unable to find the equilibrium temperature. The answer is showing 119 °C and possible range from 83 °C to 277 °C.

How do I find it mathematically? I have used the equation $\mathrm d\mu = -S\,\mathrm dT + V\,\mathrm dp,$ but lot of the things are unknown. Can anyone solve it completely with calculation?

[image: my worked out graph]

#### References

1. Castellan, G. W. Physical Chemistry, 3rd ed.; Addison-Wesley: Reading, Mass, 1983. ISBN 978-0-201-10386-1.

Comment: Ask yourself: Is there anything here that is constant, which would allow you to simplify the equation?

Comment: I already tried to solve by making chemical potential and Equilibrium temperature as constants but still failed, so I request you please solve the problem.

Comment: That's not how it works for homework problems on this site.  We're supposed to provide guidance so that you can solve it, not solve it for you.  In this problem,  and T are not constants,  they're variables.  However, p is constant, which gives you a nice simplification of the equations you're working with.

Comment: I already considered p to be constant I have used the equation du = -SdT, on integrating both sides from limits 298K to T    I got u-u° = -S (T-298) now for both Rhombic and monoclinic sulphur u must be same in equilibrium, and also T is same , since T is equilibrium temperature,     now Gf for rhombic sulphur is zero and Gf for monoclinic sulphur is 63, both values are given so  and for rhombic S =31.88 and for monoclinic S=32.55 so using the equation u =-Sdt for both the sulphur we get       u -0= -31.88(T-298) and u - 63= -32.55(T-298) these two equations u is same so we find the equil temp

Comment: But in the above mentioned way which I did my answer is coming very weird T is coming -25°C but actual answer is 119°C

Comment: You've got it set up correctly, so your problem seems to be just with the algebra:  When I set -31.88 (T- 298) = 63 - 32.55 (T - 298), and solve for T, I get T = 392 K = 119 C.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98971/discussion-between-sayantan-bhanja-and-theorist).

Comment: Yes  thank you very much, I found it, Yeah I found out, I was so close just problem with algebra and signs, now what I realised is There was no need to post this question here when I had already solved it on my own, but since due to calculation mistake I was not sure about my approach I thought my approach is wrong, I became very scared and lost my confidence

Comment: Are the uncertainty ranges [83,277] those you calculated or as reported by the textbook?

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I was able to help.  The last piece of this would be to use the uncertainties to find the range of different possible temperatures for phase coexistence.

Comment: Uncertainty ranges are reported by the textbook